# GitHub for Windows: adding several files to the gitignore file at once

Tags: github

When committing in [GitHub for Windows](https://windows.github.com/), is there any way to add several files to the gitignore file at once, through GitHub for Windows's GUI?

[image]

Right clicking on one file just give me the option to add this file or this extension to the gitignore file.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub for Windows doesn't allow users to adding several files to the gitignore file at once. One has to instead edit the `.gitignore` fie manually.